# Puppeteer download failing to install chromium as of 8/15/2019

Tags: puppeteer

As of yesterday (08/15/2019) Puppeteer install is failing to download chromium.   Gets a 403 from storage.googleapis.com.  Looks like maybe this is a change on google's side and puppeteer should be using commondatastorage.googleapis.com as the base download url?  Just wondering if anyone else is seeing this problem.
I am aware we can skip the chromium download, but we need it for unit tests on a build server that does not have chrome installed.

Updating to latest puppeteer (1.19.0) made no difference.

> puppeteer@1.19.0 install /node_modules/puppeteer
>   node install.js

```
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r674921! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/674921/chrome-mac.zip
    at response (<project dir>/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js:232:21)
    at ClientRequest.requestCallback (<project dir>/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js:297:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:555:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (<project dir>/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<project dir>/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:64:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Comment: It's downloading 100% perfectly on my region. I think google was in outage in some area last night.

Comment: Thanks, it's working again for me now too, so must have been a google outage as you say.  Surprisingly long as it was out yesterday and most of the morning, but seems to be back now.  Thanks for the comment, it let me know it was worth trying again.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```